# How to create refresh button upon user request for a long-time query?

Tags: python, database, flask

I've a simple app written in the Flask microframework. The main page as follows:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
   # ...
   # connect to the database
   # execute a query
   # retrieve a data
   # ...
   return render_template('index.html', out=data_from_the_database)
```

Above function produce a web page with data from the Oracle database. The problem is complex, long-time query which execution time taken about ~10-15 minutes on the database and almost 100% CPU time on the server.

I have an idea to resolve this problem:

1. Every day at 2:00 AM, using `cURL` tool I want to open the main page, and
2. Using the `pickle` module save data to a file, and
3. Create "REFRESH" button on the page to manually refresh actual data from the database.

**My main question is how to achieve the following two assumptions:**

1. When the user call the main page ("/") in the browser he/she get data from the file.
2. When the user want to fresh data he/she presses the "REFRESH" button and the query is executed again.

Please give me some tips, ideas (or code) how to realize this?

Comment: Looks like a good use case for [Flask-cache](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/). Take a look.

Answer (score 2):

You can just call the "REFRESH" part using POST (via a form). Something like the following:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # pull data from database
        # update the data file. If does not exist, then create it first time

    # Now, retrieve the data from the data file. This will always be called even with GET request

    data = <data from file>     

    # Return the data back to the client.    
    return render_template('index.html', out=data)
```

In the code above, you will doing 2 extra steps using POST. Step 1 will pull data from database and step 2 will update the data file that you have. If data file does not exist yet, it should be created in that step. Rest will be same.

In your `index.html` or template, just make sure you have the following form:

```
<form action= {{url_for('index')}} method='POST'>
<input type='submit' value="REFRESH'>
</form>
.....
```

Comment: Thank you! :-) Your solution/code is really neat, but I've one additional question. How about with automatically generate data and file at 2:00 AM? How do I call the ```curl``` tool in cron? Maybe I should call the ```index``` function directly from the Python in cron? Best regards, Scottie